# Jquery validation on submit-handler missing form data

Tags: jquery, validation, submit

I want to call some ajax when form validation is passed. the problem is that my form data seems to be lost in the submit-handler.

This is my code:

```
$(function(){

     $("#ticketSubmit").validate({

          rules:{

               name:{
                    required: true
               }
         }

         submitHandler:function(form){

               var dataString=$(this).serialize();

               alert(dataString);

               return false;

         }

     });

)};
```

I have created this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5pC/5/

Answer (score 3):

You had a number of formatting issues, also the reason $(this) doesnt work in your example is because $(this) is a reference to your validator and not the form. You can use this.currentForm though no problem.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ticketSubmit").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var dataString = $(this.currentForm).serialize();
            alert(dataString);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5pC/9/

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok so I have to use:

var dataString=$(form).serialize();

Why does this not work:

var dataString=$(this).serialize();

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the validate object, not the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between `rules` and `submitHandler` attributes.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ticketSubmit").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            alert(dataString);
            return false;
        }
    });
    )
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ce29u/

Comment: that was a typo, my original code has the commar and I get no form data when using $(this)